# Instead of week number, is it possible to get a date range?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

```
structure(list(ReviewType= c("Primary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Primary", "Secondary"), Submissiondate= c("2020-09-04", "2020-09-03","2020-09-02","2020-09-01","2020-08-31" ),Channel= c("OC", "BC","BC","BC","PK" )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I have a query below and others too that i would like to edit such that instead of giving me the week number, it tells me the date range of that week:

```
FinalCounting<-Out %>%
  group_by(Year = year(Submissiondate), Week = week(Submissiondate)) %>% 
  summarise(Primary = sum(ReviewType == "Primary"), 
            Secondary = sum(ReviewType == "Secondary"))
```

When the query is run, it gives out a output like this:
[image]

If instead of 36, i get 2020-08-31 - 2020-09-04 or even just the last date of this range so i can call it As of Reporting date, is that possible? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please provide `dput(head(Out))` in the question

Comment: It's there now.

Comment: Piccinin1992, that `structure` you pasted is invalid. It makes sense to me to remove one extra right-paren, but it is apparent that you did something to it when you copied it from your console (such as to remove sensitive/unnecessary data, which is fine). Please [edit] again to include a valid structure. Thanks!

Comment: Please see now, hopefully this is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a column with `Week = paste(lubridate::floor_date(Submissiondate, unit = "weeks"), "-", lubridate::ceiling_date(Submissiondate, unit = "weeks"))`.

You should be able to put this right into the `group_by` statement or into a `mutate` before (for a little more readability).